# Is it possible to use compile time asserts in C++

Tags: c++, assert

I want to use a template for some data processing, but I need the code to be more or less safe when ported.

This might be a problem if sizes of variables grow beyond anticipated values, so I would like to assert at compile time that some assumptions are still valid.

For example, `sizeof(long)>sizeof(int)`, so that if this assumption fails, I could break the build.

I know that standard mandates that `long>=int`, but this is just an example, don't concentrate on the variable types.

Comment: See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html

Comment: What is your question? In c++11 there is `static_assert`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 has `static_assert`:

```
static_assert(sizeof(long) > sizeof(int), "long must be greater than int");
```

On older compilers you can use [Boost.StaticAssert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert.html).

```
BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(long) > sizeof(int));
```

Comment: Is it possible to implement this feature without boost on older compilers? Is it a template trick internally?

Comment: @Coder The documentation has a page explaining [how it works](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_staticassert/how.html) if you want to implement it yourself. That and a peek at the actual implementation should be enough.

Comment: @coder you can see an implementation for older compilers here: http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/static_assert.html

Comment: One that is missing from the link is similar to the one in the linux kernel, but defining a new type: `#define static_assert(x) typedef char assert_##__line__[ 1-2*!(x)];` (or something similar, I never got my head around the preprocessor and the ## operator...