# Parsing char array efficiently in C

Tags: c++, c, arrays, embedded, byte

I want to parse the char array efficiently. What is the correct way to do this in c. I'm new to c programming.  Please guide me.

data is 32 byte. 1st byte is version, 2nd and 3rd bytes are sequence number and so on as listed below.

```
void parsepacket(u8_t data[]) {
    u8_t version = data[0];
    u16_t sequence_number = ?;
    u16_t error_status = ?;
    u8_t command_type = ?;
    u8_t attribute_count = ?;
    u8_t pay_load[25] = ?;
}
```

Comment: you should use `struct`

Comment: `payload` is one word BTW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for...

```
void parsepacket(const u8_t data[]) {  //same as u8_t*data
        u8_t version;
        u16_t sequence_number;
        u16_t error_status;
        u8_t command_type;
        u8_t attribute_count;
        u8_t pay_load[25];
        u8_t i =0;
        version = data[i];
        i++;
        sequence_number =(u16_t)(8<<data[i] + data[i+i]);
        i+=2;
        error_status = (u16_t)(8<<data[i] + data[i+i]);
        i+=2;
        attribute_count = data[i];
        i++;
        for(int j=0;j<25;j++)
          pay_load[j] = data[i++];
    }
```

Comment: Is this the effective way?

Comment: This assumes Big Endian byte order, which may, or may not work for you.

Comment: you can do a memcopy and use appropriate pointers to avoid shift operations but I think the idea was, how to read the data...

Answer (score 0):

Array is for similar data type for example you can array of data type u8_t or u16_t etc, In this case it would be good if you pass it as a reference to structure for e.g

```
typedef struct {
u8_t version;
u16_t sequence_number;
u16_t error_status;
u8_t command_type;
u8_t attribute_count;
u8_t pay_load[25];
..
} data_seq;

void parsepacket(data_seq *input) {

}
```

data_seq *ptr_dataseq;
call it using

```
parsepacket(&ptr_dataseq);
```

Comment: Actually I want to parse the data from "data[]" or *data.  I've done some changes in code.

Comment: That doesn't work, because of the lack of attribute 'packed'; and even then on some CPU architectures (often in embedded world) strict alignment prevents uint16_t extraction from non-aligned address.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't need to make portable code, you can first try to make a packed struct, which by definition removes padding or alignment to the same granularity of each element.

In gcc (you may need to consult the developer's manual of your tool chain) it's done with

```
struct __attribute__((__packed__)) foo {
     u8_t data;
     u16_t version;
     ...
     u8_t payload[25];
```

};

You also may need to instrument the code (by ASSERTING) that `sizeof(struct foo) == 32`.
That itself is a bit [tricky to do with preprocessor, but doable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10866775/1716339) (See the comment also).

The next issue is to check that the architecture allows reading words from non-word boundaries. One clue can be that the c-compiler warns about deviating from strict alignment rules, which should be taken seriously.

One possibility is to hard code the conversion, as already mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20419866/1716339). If this is a reoccurring pattern, then it may be worth to build a runtime parser, parsing eg.

```
int data(char *input, size_t input_length, const char *fmt_string, void *result)
{
   switch (*fmt_string)
   {
       case '\0':  break;
       case 'b' : 
          *result = input++; break;
       case 'w' :
          result = align_to(result, sizeof(uint16_t));
          *(uint16_t *)result = get_word(input);
          input+=sizeof(uint16_t); break;
    }
}
```

Which would parse e.g. the string "bWWbb25b", where the capitalization could optionally denote the endianness.

Comment: Here the question of byte order is externalized to the function get_word().

Answer (score 0):

The most 'efficient' method may depend on a number of factors such as:

- whether the byte order in the array is the same as that in a `u16_t`,
- whether the target machine allows byte aligned 16 bit words,
- whether your compiler supports a method of structure packing
- how portable or machine/compiler specific you want the code to be.
- whether you need to copy the data or simply reinterpret it with an overlayed struct (zero copy)

Answers for most of these scenarios have already been given.

That said, it is only 32 bytes - how efficient does this really need to be?  You may be better off aiming for clarity, and portability over performance if it will meet your performance constraints in any case.